Syncing Excel SharePoint cells when updates are generated from VBA code
I created an Excel UserForm to input information. From that information, data is generated and written to the next blank row in a table.
When I test it as a single user, it works.
I started testing in a multi-user environment. The document is hosted on SharePoint.
Normally, cell changes on Excel SharePoint are visible nearly instantly to other users who have the document open. I am trialling this new system with colleagues and I am unable to see the updates at my end.
I surmise that the problem stems from cell updates being written by VBA code, Cells.Value = Variable, rather than being typed by my colleagues.
In the past, I would have used Excel as a front-end and an Access database as a back-end: however, that requires hosting the file on a network drive, and my company instructs that everything should be on SharePoint.
